# How to recreate this "default-like" look with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, matcaps

could somebody please help me to recreate this particular look with the cycles render engine?

[image]

I want to create this specific default-like look to present my 3D scans with all their fine details and render single images of it with a very high resolution.

It looks like a mixture between a clay-like material, sharp shadows and fine outlines.

I know, that this image was rendered with Marmoset Toolbag. I was able to get close to it with Workbench + Matcaps, but to render in high resolution I think cycles would be better?

I am very thankful for any ideas!

Comment: What makes you think that rendering in Cycles would be better for this? For the sort of look you’re going for, I would expect Workbench or Freestyle to be a better bet.

Comment: The problem I have with workbench is that when I try to render in a very high resolution (12.000 x 10.000 px) Blender always crashes (my hardware is not the best).

For rendering with Cycles I am using a render farm which doesn’t support renderings with workbench…

Do you maybe have any tipps for using workbench as a final high-res rendering engine? Or do you know a render farm which supports workbench?

Comment: @ldw.blend  Workbench is the level zero of render engines.

Comment: Meanwhile, I would say a principled BSDF set to half metallic would do the job. Will test tomorrow ITLW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

1. Go to "[your Blender installation
   folder] \ [version]\datafiles\studiolights\matcap" and select your matcap.
2. make a node setup like above. (note that values in mapping node are changed)
3. add a sun.
4. from here on you can adjust the nodes and sun to mimic workbench more.

here is basic 2 matcap with sun strength to 3:
[image]

my node setup is sourced from this video: https://youtu.be/QdlBB4-uW_E

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much!